# SQL Select: Joining 3 tables and do on the last table an count

Tags: php, sql, join, count, datatables

i have 3 tables and want to do a JOIN with them. -> No problem with that! 
Here comes my challenge... i am not able to solve:

The last table I am adding is the table "attachments". But I want to do a **count** on this table to get the number of rows for the filter: WHERE attachments.audit_id = ... AND attachments.question_id = ...

I dont know now how to use the count method in this query.

*Beside this complication i have a general question to SQL JOIN: In my code i use the WHERE after the JOINs. Is this affecting now all tables so the whole query? or only the tables i am using on the beginning of the attribute?*

Here is my try so far....

```html
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT  
                                    answers.question_id, 
                                    answers.rating, 
                                    questions.id, 
                                    questions.chapter_number, 
                                    questions.custom_question_number, 
                                    questions.question_header_text, 
                                    questions.question, 
                                    questions.critical_question, 
                                    questions.question_information 
                                    
                            FROM answers 
                            INNER JOIN questions ON answers.question_id = questions.id 
                            INNER JOIN attachments
                            WHERE questions.questionaire_id = :questionaire_id AND questions.chapter_number = :chapter_number
                            ORDER BY questions.id ASC ");
$statement->execute(array(':questionaire_id' => '1', ':chapter_number' => '2')); 
 
                            $count = 1;
                            while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

> The last table I am adding is the table "attachments". But I want to
>   do a count on this table to get the number of rows for the filter:
>   WHERE attachments.audit_id = ... AND attachments.question_id = ...

just do it in another query

> Beside this complication i have a general question to SQL JOIN: In my
>   code i use the WHERE after the JOINs. Is this affecting now all tables
>   so the whole query? or only the tables i am using on the beginning of
>   the attribute?

first `join` statement combines tables by specified criteria like this `JOIN questions ON answers.question_id = questions.id` then `where` statement filter joined data by criteria

order of execution of sql instructions (MySQL):

1. FROM, JOINs
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. WINDOW
6. SELECT
7. DISTINCT
8. UNION
9. ORDER BY
10. LIMIT, OFFSET

Comment: "just do it in another query" But i am dong a row fetch... it will result only the first row i think?

"first join statement combines tables by specified criteria like this JOIN questions ON answers.question_id = questions.id then where statement filter joined data by criteria"
So if i join > 3 tables i still use the WHERE at the end and filter by "table.attribute"?

Comment: 1. if you will do something like this to count `select count(*) from table` it will be only one row in result, so that all you need to fetch for count rows

Comment: 2. you join data from another tables by some `ON` statement, after you filter  unnecessary joined rows by `where`. note: you use `inner join`